# Update instead of delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm developing a webapp with Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5, which will manage some industrial process. One of the requirements is that, when someone wants to delete a registry, the delete task will have to make an update to one of the fields of the DB table. This field establishes if a record is active or not.

I have modified the default delete method generated by the scaffold:

```
def activar
  @alarma = Alarma.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @alarma.update_attribute(:estado_id => 1)
      flash[:notice] = 'La alarma ha sido activada.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@alarma) }
      format.xml { head :ok }
    else
     format.html { render :action => "index" } 
     format.xml { render :xml => @alarmas }
    end
  end
end

def desactivar
  @alarma = Alarma.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @alarma.update_attribute(:estado_id => 2)
      flash[:notice] = 'La alarma fue desactivada.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@alarma) }
      format.xml { head :ok }
    else
     format.html { render :action => "index" } 
     format.xml { render :xml => @alarmas }
    end
  end
end
```

where `:estado_id => 1` is active, and `:estado_id => 2` is deactive. However, when a I try to do the update, it doesn't change the attribute. Actually, it doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Please follow Rails convention. Call your field `is_active` and simply set it to true or false.

Comment: @meager: "Rails convention" would probably have the field called `active` and be a boolean, no `is` prefix required :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) in your case

> update_attributes(attributes) public
>
> Updates all the attributes from the
>   passed-in Hash and saves the record.
>   If the object is invalid, the saving
>   will fail and false will be returned.

example:

```
@user.update_attributes(:status => 'active')
```

or `@alarma.update_attribute(:estado_id, 2)` if you want to use [update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute)

> update_attribute(name, value) public
>
> Updates a single attribute and saves
>   the record without going through the
>   normal validation procedure.